# Angularjs service does not perform more than one http request

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-http

I have a problem with a service angularjs , do not make more than one http request .

**The service :**

```
.factory('checkpoints', function($http, user_auth) {
            var promise = $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: remote_ws + 'index/',
                data: user_auth.get,
                cache:false
            }).
                    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        if (data.result == "OK") {
                            window.localStorage.setItem("last_id", data.update[0].last_id);
                            window.localStorage.setItem("last_count", data.update[0].last_count);
                        }
                        return data;
                    }).
                    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        data.result = "ERROR";
                        data.status = status;
                        return data;
                    });
            return promise;
        })
```

**In the controller:**

```
var UpdateCheckpoints = function() {
        checkpoints.then(function(promise) {
            if (promise.data.result == "OK") {
                $scope.map.checkpoints = promise.data.markers;
                _.each($scope.map.checkpoints, function(marker) {
                    marker.distance = $scope.c_distance(marker);
                    marker.onClicked = function() {
                        onMarkerClicked(marker.id);
                    };
                });
            } else {
                $location.search({error: true, error_text: session_error}).path("/login");
                if (!$scope.$$phase) {
                    $scope.$apply();
                }
            }
        })
```

When I call : UpdateCheckpoints ( ), the result is null.

Is done only the first request.

It is a problem with **$http** or statement of **service**?

Comment: What's `null`, the promise.data or the result of factory?

Comment: does not make a second http request, i meant "the result is nothing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.understanding_services):

> Angular services are singletons objects or functions ...
>
> The purpose of the service factory function is to generate the single
>   object, or function, that represents the service to the rest of the
>   application.

Try changing your factory to something along these lines:

```
app.factory('checkpointService', function($http, user_auth) {

  return {
    getCheckpoints: function() {

      return $http({
          method: "POST",
          url: remote_ws + 'index/',
          data: user_auth.get,
          cache: false
        })
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          if (data.result == "OK") {
            window.localStorage.setItem("last_id", data.update[0].last_id);
            window.localStorage.setItem("last_count", data.update[0].last_count);
          }
          return data;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          data.result = "ERROR";
          data.status = status;
          return data;
        });
    }
  };
});
```

And call it with:

```
checkpointService.getCheckpoints().then(function(promise) { ...
```

Now the `checkpointService` will be a singleton object, but everytime you call `getCheckpoints` a new call via the `$http` service should be made.